# To prove the equivalence of the induction principles, why does it seems we assume what we want to prove?

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

I've been trying to understand the proof of equivalence of induction, from Gunderson's *Handbook of Mathematical Induction*:

> [image]
>
> [image]

The proof given in the book is as follows:

> [image]

I have looked at other sources, for example, Stillwell's *Elements of Algebra*:

> [image]

There is something I am confused: What are they doing - logically - in there? In both proofs, it seems they are trying to prove the second form of induction from the first, that is: $weak \implies strong$, what confuses me is that (I guess) they both suppose that what they are trying to prove is true. I guess the most clear proof I've found was in an article by [A. Schach](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3029535) and it is as follows:

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

And yet, it seems to be assuming what was to be proved again. What is happening?

Comment: Objective to prove is $P(n)$ for all $n$. Assumptions are $P(1)$ and $Q(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$ for all $n$. (I just read the last one)

Comment: Stillwell's proof looks really strange to me.  Isn't it obvious that I $\implies$ II?  The hypothesis in I is weaker than in II.  It seems like I implies II a fortiori.  Am I misunderstanding something, or is something omitted from the excerpt that would explain this?

Comment: $(2)$ corresponds to the line only, not 'are given, then $P(n)$ for all $n$'

Comment: @saulspatz I believe II $\implies$ I follows by $T2$ (from last proof) immediately. But for other direction, II assumes all up to $n$ to imply $n+1$, instead of $P(n)$ only. I am not sure how it is immediate.

Comment: @Atbey No, that's backwards.  If it's enough to know that $n\in S$ then surely it's enough to know that $0,1,2,...,n\in S.$  The other direction is tricky.  Given that it's enough to know  $0,1,2,...,n\in S$ show that we *really* only have to know $n\in S.$

Comment: @saulspatz I will read the proof you are referring, but let me correct my above comment first. Suppose II. If $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$, then $P(1)\&\dots\& P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$(By T3). By II, $P(n)$ for all $n$.

Comment: Can you say exactly what step you think is "assuming what is to be proved"?

Answer (score 1):

> There is something I am confused: What are they doing - logically - in there? In both proofs, it seems they are trying to prove the second form of induction from the first, that is: weak⟹strong, what confuses me is that (I guess) they both suppose that what they are trying to prove is true.

Names are deceiving. Strong induction is NOT a stronger form of induction. In fact, strong induction and induction (and also the well ordering of $\mathbb{N}$) are equivalent. This means they imply each other. Your quoted proofs are proving that normal induction implies strong induction. There should be a proof of the converse somewhere else in the book.

Comment: There is a proof. But I'm asking specifically about this one.